# Why does this Biot-Savart expression need to be changed when $z < a$?

Tags: electromagnetism

[image: Assignment problem]

I have to represent the magnetic field of this set up with a power series. I'm asked to give an expression for $z > b$ and $z < a$. Why would the expression change for either of them, can't both situations be represented by the same series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your one task is to come up with an approximation
   for the inner region, i.e. for $0\le z < a$.
   This can be done by a power-series of the form
   $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n.$$
   This series will be quickly convergent for small $z$,
   but probably divergent for $z\ge a$.
2. Your other task is to come up with an approximation
   for the outer region, i.e. for $b\lt z < \infty$.
   This can be done by a power-series of the form
   $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \frac{1}{z^n}.$$
   This series will be quickly convergent for large $z$,
   but probably divergent for $z\le b$.

Hence you won't be able to get a power-series convergent for the whole range of $z$.

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the help!